# Possible to define new unit, comparable to pt or em?

Tags: tex-core, units

Pre-defined LaTeX units, such as pt or em, are used this way:

```
\newlength\somelength
\setlength\somelength{3.5em}
```

That is, the multiplier goes directly in front of the units, without an intervening backslash. TeX knows that `em' is a particular size, depending on layout.

I can do this:

```
\newlength\bs % where \bs is not otherwise used
\setlength\bs{11.46pt}
\newlength\somelength
\setlength\somelength{3.5\bs}
```

But I ask, can it be done without the need for backslash? I am not referring to "SIunits" here. Desired pseudo-code:

```
\newmeasurement\bs
\setmeasurement\bs{11.46pt}
\newlength\somelength
\setlength\somelength{3.5bs} % no backslash needed
```

Is there an "easy" way to do that, which has general applicability? I am using LuaLaTeX with TeXlive 2016, but hope that deep in the TeX core there is some simple way to do this, which I have not discovered. Earlier search came up with ways to format units, rather than define them as fundamentals.

If question is unrealistic, I will accept that. Can't have everything.

EDIT: Apparently not easy to do. When I asked the question, I thought maybe there was a single command that I did not know. So it can be closed.

Comment: In legacy TeX engines this is not possible, as only a fixed set of keywords is accepted.

Comment: @egreg How far back is "legacy"? The target audience for my code will at least be using LaTeX 2e. Probably all will be using LuaTeX with TeXlive 2016, just as I am. If necessary, I can limit use of the new measurement to those who have the proper TeX engine. But I cannot use XeTeX, for other reasons.

Comment: Legacy = not LuaTeX

Comment: @egreg All right, a LuaTeX solution is perfectly acceptable. When I first asked the question, I hoped that a "legacy" answer might be of benefit to other users.

Comment: You've tagged [tag:tex-core]: are we allowed to suggest a macro-level approach? (It should be possible to modify `\setlength` to cover the requirement.)

Comment: I tagged tex-core as a guess, really. A macro would be just as good. My own attempts with `\setlength` fail, because it is necessary to use the backslash when calling that length (as far as I know). Rationale: The "natural" horizontal unit is `em`. So I can write `\hspace{2.4em}`. The "natural" vertical unit is baselineskip. My concept was to create a unit representing the skip, whatever value it has. Then I could write `\vspace{1.8bs}` or whatever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the comments state the units that are know to TeX are implemented
in the Pascal source. But macros can be written to do what you want as
Joseph Wright points out in his comment.

Two assumptions:

1. Use for the unit two characters as it is done by TeX for all other
   units. (It avoids a lot of tests.)
2. Use the new unit always as a macro parameter in curly braces.

I show the general approach for two macros `\Setlength` and `\Hspace`,
which are mentioned in your question and your comments. Note I do not
change the LaTeX macros.

I write the macros in plain TeX style. The macros do not check if the
unit is a known unit like pt. So they can only be used with your own
units. Moreover they do not give useful error messages if they are
called with an unknown unit. As I wrote I only give the general
approach to attack the problem.

```
\newdimen\ownunitdimen

\def\rev#1#2\rev{\ifx\rev#2\rev#1\else\rev#2\rev#1\fi}% a TeX pearl
\def\applyownunit#1#2#3\done{% needs \#2#1factor and \#2#1unit
   \global\ownunitdimen=\rev #3\rev\csname #2#1unit\endcsname
   \global\ownunitdimen=\csname #2#1factor\endcsname\ownunitdimen\ignorespaces}

\def\Setlength#1#2{\bgroup\edef\reverse{\rev #2\rev}%
   \expandafter\applyownunit\reverse\done\egroup
   \csname #1\endcsname=\ownunitdimen}
\def\Hspace#1{\bgroup\edef\reverse{\rev #1\rev}%
   \expandafter\applyownunit\reverse\done\egroup
   \hskip\ownunitdimen\relax}

% define new units; avoid dimen registers
\def\dmfactor{10}\def\dmunit{cm}% 1 dm = 10 cm
\def\pzfactor{2.2633484517438}\def\pzunit{mm} % 1 pz \approx 2.2633484517438 mm
% see page 26 of ``Selected Papers on Fun \& Games'' by Donald E. Knuth

% test
\newdimen\A \newdimen\B
\Setlength{A}{8.97dm}% use the new unit
\B=89.7cm %      and compare it to this

A: \the\A \Hspace{5,2pz}B: \the\B\par % use the new unit in European style
A: \the\A \hskip11.76941194906776mm B: \the\B % and compare

% I think this is better
\newdimen\pz \pz=2.2633484517438mm
A: \the\A \hskip5.2\pz B: \the\B

\bye
```

Comment: Wow. I'll have a long look at that. Programming directly in TeX is not what I know how to do. Although the curly braces complicate it slightly, it looks adequate for the purpose. Surprised that this question drew an answer, after such time!

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to iterate token-by-token, extract a two-letter unit and see if it's been defined. To allow macros to be hidden there, I've used `\expanded` to force expansion: this could be avoided. Similarly, I've allowed the new unit to be specified as a (standard) e-TeX dimension expression: we could allow new units there too.

The trick to picking up letters *versus* everything else to to use the character code: in this way, we have a very easy test:

```latex
\protected\def\setlength#1#2{%
  \expandafter\setlengthauxi\expandafter#1\expanded{#2}\relax{}%
}
\protected\def\setlengthauxi#1#2{%
  \ifx#2\relax
    \expandafter\setlengthnounit
  \fi
  \ifnum 0%
    \ifnum`#2<`a 1\fi%
    \ifnum`#2>`z 1\fi%
    >0 %
    \expandafter\setlengthstore
  \else
    \expandafter\setlengthletter
  \fi
    #1#2%
}
\protected\def\setlengthstore#1#2#3\relax#4{%
  \setlengthauxi#1#3\relax{#4#2}%
}
\protected\def\setlengthletter#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#3\relax
    \expandafter\ERROR
  \fi
  \setlengthletterauxi#1{#2#3}%
}
\protected\def\setlengthletterauxi#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#3\relax
  \else
    \expandafter\ERROR
  \fi
  \setlengthletterauxii#1{#2}%
}
\protected\def\setlengthletterauxii#1#2#3{%
  \ifcsname unit@\expandafter\string\csname#2\endcsname\endcsname
    #1 = #3\csname unit@\expandafter\string\csname#2\endcsname\endcsname\relax
  \else
    #1 = #3#2\relax
  \fi
}
\protected\def\setlengthnounit#1\setlengthletter\fi#2#3#4{#2 = #4 }
\protected\def\newlength#1{\csname newskip\endcsname#1}
\protected\def\newmeasurement#1#2{%
  \expandafter\newlength\csname unit@\string#1\endcsname
  \csname unit@\string#1\endcsname = \dimexpr#2\relax\relax
}

\newmeasurement\bs{11.46pt}
\newlength\somelength
\setlength\somelength{3.5bs}
\showthe\somelength
```